# GraphStream Thread synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, graphstream

I'am trying to create a tool for demonstrating graphs and algorithms. For that purpose I've found GraphStream library. I have read all of its documentation and tutorials but I cant make this one thing work. I am trying to put graph into my custom GUI (left menu with buttons and right graph space) and i managed to do that. Now when i enabled two buttons: generate - creates graph with random generator, and clear - clears graph, it all works fine but after clear when i press generate, i get following error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-2" org.miv.pherd.IdAlreadyInUseException:
>   a particle with the same identifier already exists (0)

I dont understand why this is a problem because in my simple test program without gui, i made simple code in main to do the same thing and it works:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args){

     Graph graph = new SingleGraph("test");

      graph.display();

      Generator generator = new BarabasiAlbertGenerator();
      generator.addSink(graph);
      generator.begin();
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      generator.nextEvents();
      }

      generator.end();

      graph.clear();
      generator = new BarabasiAlbertGenerator();
      generator.addSink(graph);
      generator.begin();
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      generator.nextEvents();
      }
      generator.end();


}
```

this code works but when i execute it within my GUI with buttons i throws error which I have mentioned above. I also checked how many threads are running in my program and it seems 3 of them are. I hope my problem is pretty clear and someone can help me. Thank you all!

Comment: A websearch quickly leads to http://sympa.litislab.fr/sympa/arc/graphstream-users/2013-09/msg00003.html - are you sure you are using a version where this bug is alredy fixed?

Comment: saw that post but didnt see that last nightly build, thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a known bug in the `BarabasiAlbertGenerator` class (see the corresponding [Graphstream users thread](http://sympa.litislab.fr/sympa/arc/graphstream-users/2013-09/msg00003.html)).

This bug is fixed in the 1.3.x versions of the libraries, which are currently available as the nightly builds at http://graphstream-project.org/pub/1.x/nightly-build/last/

(In future, this fix should be part of the [regular Graphstream downloads](http://graphstream-project.org/download/))